# Prove that a group of order 10 is either isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ or isomorphic to $D_5$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The question is to prove that a group of order 10 is either isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ or isomorphic to $D_5$. I have been looking for solutions but couldn't find an explanation without Sylow theorems, which i haven't had yet.

Comment: You don't need Sylow. Lagrange is sufficient (order of subgroups divide order of group). Do you know that one?

Comment: I know that one do not quite see how to solve it yet, (I do know that because of cauchy there are elements in the group of order 2,3,5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group of order $10$. Note that by Cauchy's Theorem there are elements of order $2$ and $5$, namely $a^2 = 1, b^5 = 1$. Now as $[G:\langle b \rangle] = 2$ we have that $\langle b \rangle$ is normal in $G$. Therefore we must have:

$$aba^{-1} = b,b^2,b^3 \text{ or }b^4$$

The first case gives us that $G$ is abelian and therefore it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ as $10$ is square-free integer. The second and third case are impossible, as:

$$b = a^2b(a^{-1})^2 = a(aba^{-1})a^{-1} = ab^2a^{-1} = b^4$$
$$b = a^2b(a^{-1})^2 = a(aba^{-1})a^{-1} = ab^3a^{-1} = b^9 = b^4$$

The fourth case is possible. Now show that:

$$(a,b: a^2 = 1, b^5 = 1, ab = ba) \quad \text{ and } \quad (a,b: a^2 = 1, b^5 = 1; ab = b^4a)$$

are two distinct subgroups of order $10$.

Comment: Sorry for the very late question, but I don't understand how you go from $ab^2a^{-1}$ to $b^4$. And also how you go from $ab^3a^{-1}$ to $b^9$.

Comment: @user423841 $ab^2a^{-1} = (aba^{-1})^2 = (b^2)^2 = b^4$. Similarly for the second one.